# R/Docker load failed for ‘networkD3’ in dyn.load

Tags: r, docker, shiny, networkd3

Im deploying a shiny app using a docker/rockerverse image.
Install.packages(networkD3) is giving the below error.
I have tried installing with dependencies = TRUE.

Has anyone any suggestions?

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘networkD3’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
libglpk.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Execution halted

Comment: Have you verified that the optional igraph system dependency libglpk is installed? Apparently it’s needed here (but missing), and it probably won’t be installed by default since it’s optional under normal circumstances.

Comment: Thanks a mil.    To install networkD3  - I had to install igraph and to install igraph I had to install ggdag and add this code to my dockerfile.                                                 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  libglpk40